# How to download images served by ASPX?

Tags: python, web-scraping, urllib2

Currently I have a python script that logins to a website. I want to download an image off the website but I have a problem. The website serves the image with a ASPX extension.

```
<img style="-webkit-user-select: none" src="http://xxx/JpegImage.aspx?r=1234">
```

My python code to dl images.

```
from urllib.request import Request, urlopen, urlretrieve
urlretrieve("imgUrl", "local-filename.jpg") #imgURL is http://xxx/JpegImage.aspx?r=1234
```

However, this just gives me a weird, corrupt? image. My code works for any other images with other extensions such as .jpg.

I appreciate all help. Thanks.

Comment: Files with this extension contain Visual Basic script. It's intended that, when the web server encounters them that they be executed and the results offered in the web page. Since you're circumventing this mechanism you are most probably getting the script itself. It's unlikely that you can execute the script on your own computer to obtain its proper results because it was intended to execute on the server. You might try examining it to understand what it does and then do that for yourself remotely against the web server. Agony! It might be that your best bet would be to use Selenium.

Comment: Can you give us a URL that contains one of these?